# Why list behave differently while adding new elements to it?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When i **append new Element** to existing list and after showing list on screen,sometime new element show on top of list and sometime on last.
Why List behave like this?
in below code,I **want to show** that newly added element on top of my list  Is there a way to do it?

```
class _TransactionListState extends State<TransactionList> {

// Existing List with two transactions

  final List<Transaction> transactions = [
    Transaction(
      title: 'New Books',
      id: 't1',
      amount: 44.55,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      title: 'Weekly Items',
      id: 't2',
      amount: 22.44,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final amountController = TextEditingController();

  void addTransactions() {
// Add new transaction
    Transaction tx = Transaction(
        title: titleController.text,
        amount: double.parse(amountController.text),
        date: DateTime.now(),
        id: DateTime.now().toString());

    setState(() {
// Add new transaction to existing List. I want this new element on top of screen
      transactions.add(tx);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use insert() method of List to add the item, here the index would be 0 to add it in the beginning. Example:**

```
List<String> transactions = ["Items1", "Items2", "Items3"];


transactions.insert(0, "New Value");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `reverse: true` to the `ListView` constructor or you can insert the new item at the 0th index using `list.insert(index, item)` method as:

`setState(() { transactions.insert(0, tx); });`

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use stacks, you could use: https://pub.dev/packages/stack